# permission to write files in Windows Server

Tags: redhat, mount, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using redhat OS in virtual box. I have mounted my Server's (windows 2012 R2) hard disk
on my redhat(**/home/user1/myfolder**) using

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.100.1/myfolder/ /home/user1/myfolder -o username=MyRegisteredUserNameForServer
```

**Problem:**
I can read write and executes the file stored in that server.
Also, using '**sudo nano myfile.txt**' I can create a file in the mounted folder "/home/user1/myfolder" but when I try to execute any script that creates files, it says permission denied.

eg: `python myscript.py > output.txt`

```
"permission denied"
```

I tried a lot to get into it but couldn't find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

finally the below worked:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=MyRegisteredUserNameForServer,password=P@ssw0rd,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 //192.168.100.1/myfolder /home/user1/myfolder
```